# Ionic 2 - create primary gradient color

Tags: sass, ionic2

How do I set my primary color in `variables.scss` I can't do it like this:

`variables.scss:`

```
$colors: (
  // primary:    #4caefe,

  primary2: linear-gradient(to right, #0fe2f3, #4caefe),
  secondary:  #32db64,
  danger:     #f53d3d,
  light:      #fff,
  dark:       #222,
  background: #f7f7f7
);
```

this is the error message:

```
[12:53:30]  sass: ...top/GitHub/plenumo-ionic2/node_modules/ionic-angular/themes/ionic.functions.scss, line: 109
            The map color `primary` is not defined. Please make sure the color exists in your `$colors` map. For
            example: $colors: ( primary: #327eff );

     L109:    @error $error-msg;
```

How do I set the primary color to the gradient I would like to set?

And here is the code where I use the variable:

```
.play-btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border: 1px solid map-get($colors, primary);
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: transparent;
    background: map-get($colors, primary2);

    .ion-md-icon-play_1 {
        margin-left: 3px;
    }
}
```

It is not possible to change simply the primary variable so It is used on every element which uses primary variable? Because gradients only works on `backround property`

Comment: What sass version are you using?

Comment: It looks like the issue is how you are setting the color of an element  as primary rather than how you are initializing it..

Comment: @suraj I tried to create an other variable `primary2` for example, and than asign it as background-image but still the same error

Comment: can you add the code where you are setting the color to the element?

Answer (score 0):

It is well set. Maybe you have some trouble getting the color...

```
$colors: (
  primary:    linear-gradient(#0fe2f3, #4caefe),
  secondary:  #32db64,
  danger:     #f53d3d,
  light:      #fff,
  dark:       #222,
  background: #f7f7f7
);

.color{
  background-image: map-get($colors, primary);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, try to remove or rename "background" key in your map, it may cause an error I guess.
In other ways your code working perfect, you can check the output [here](https://gist.github.com/hirdbluebird/de87dd5ef8753523890da11bf91542d5).
Give me the error massage with active "primary" key if it not helped to you.